# Flink Job Testing with MiniClusterWithClientResource

Tags: unit-testing, testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've wrote a `@Test` method in order to test the execuction of a Flink job.
This is the method:

```
@Test
void testFlinkJob() throws Exception {    
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(2);

    MyJob.buildJob(env, new MySourceFunction(), new MySinkFunction());

    env.execute();

    //asserts
}
```

Implementations details of `MyJob.buildJob()`, `MySourceFunction` and `MySinkFunction` are not important. Please, focus on `env.setParallelism(2)`.

If I run this test, everything is ok. Fine!

However, Flink official documentation (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/testing/#junit-rule-miniclusterwithclientresource), speaks about `MiniClusterWithClientResource` .

So I added these snippet to my test class, as showed into documentation.

```
@ClassRule
public static MiniClusterWithClientResource flinkCluster =
        new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
                new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                        .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
                        .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                        .build());
```

I run my test again and it still passes. Perfect!

Then I started to play with the above snippet. The first thing I changed is the value of `setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager()` param from 2 to 1.

I launched a one more time my test. This time I expected a test failure because the value of parallelism (2) is higher than the value numberOfTaskManager * numberSlotPerTestManagers (1).
Instead, my test continues to pass.
Same thing if I write setNumberTaskManagers(0) (No TaskManager). Test continues to pass.

Seems that MiniClusterWithClientResource is dummy. Can you help my to understand how it work, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with JUnit 5, `@ClassRule` annotation will be ignored. You need to use extensions:

```java
@ExtendWith(MiniClusterExtension.class)
public class MyTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    public static final MiniClusterExtension MINI_CLUSTER_RESOURCE = new MiniClusterExtension(
            new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                    .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
                    .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                    .build());
}
```

**P.S.:** `MiniClusterExtension.class` is still marked as `@Experimental` as of v1.16 and therefore subject to changes.